# I want to change the output with two buttons of YES and NO in message box

Tags: winapi, assembly, messagebox

This is the code of assembler and it shows output with a message box "Hello world" along with the button "OK". What i need is to get output with the message box and have two buttons with 'Yes" and "No" and it should terminate when we click "No" button

```
extrn MessageBoxA : proc
extrn ExitProcess : proc
extern SetConsoleTitleA : proc
extern WriteConsoleA : proc
extrn GetStdHandle : proc

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11 

.data
handle dq ?
MsBoxCaption db "Sample dialogbox header",0; 
MsBoxText db "Hello world",0;
ConsoleText db "Hello, world!", 0;
ConsoleTextLen = $-ConsoleText;
Text db "This is title",0;
NumCharsWritten dw ?

.code

main proc 
sub rsp, 28h

mov ecx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle
mov [handle], rax 

lea rcx,Text
call SetConsoleTitleA

xor r9d,r9d
lea r8, MsBoxCaption;
lea rdx, MsBoxText;
xor ecx,ecx
call MessageBoxA

mov rcx, [handle]
lea rdx, ConsoleText
mov r8d, ConsoleTextLen
mov r9w, NumCharsWritten
call WriteConsoleA

mov rcx, 0;
call ExitProcess

add rsp,28h
main endp

end
```

Comment: Do you know what WinAPI function calls you'd want to make to make that happen?  Presumably different args to MessageBoxA.  Figure that out in C or C++, then do it in asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly, as Peter says, you should consult the documentation for `MessageBox()` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) before asking such a simple question, then you won't get voted down, but I think you want to change:

```
xor r9d,r9d
```

to:

```
mov r9d, MB_YESNO        ; = 4
```

and then compare the value returned in `eax` against IDNO (= 7).

Is that enough to get you going?

Comment: thank u sir for this